# Undo stage hunk in magit

Tags: magit

If I accidentally staged a hunk that I wanted a better look at, how do I undo that action (the most recent action). `C-/` does not work.

Sure I can `U` to unstage all, but say all else staged is valid.

Comment: https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Staging-and-Unstaging.html

Comment: Did you try selecting the hunk and then doing `u`? That works for me.

Comment: The thing is, when this happens and there are many hunks, it get's lost in the stage.

Comment: The take-away from this is to take greater care when staging changes for any commit.  If you have multiple changes in progress, don't just "stage all" (or don't stage all changes for a file).  Ultimately, whether you're staging each change piecemeal, or "staging all changes" and then *unstaging* certain changes, you need to confirm each hunk of the commit.  The bottom line is: Always review your commits.

Answer (score 1):

In the list of staged changes, move to the accidentally staged change and press <kbd>u</kbd> (which unstaged the hunk or file at point, just like <kbd>s</kbd> stages the change at point).

There is no undo command which would revert the last change. You do have to locate the accidentally staged change manually.

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1,

`M-x magit-unstage`

Solution 2:

Any commit/patch/diff could be opened in `diff-mode`. Then `M-x diff-apply-hunk` to apply hunk. `C-u M-x diff-apply-hunk` to undo hunk.

Actually, you don't need switch to `diff-mode` from `magit-revision-mode` at all, simple `diff-apply-hunk` is enough.

Extra tip:

If you use `smex` or `counsel-M-x` from `counsel`, when you type `M-x some-keyword`, all related commands are displayed.

[image]

As you can see, there are other commands to upstage/undo a hunk.

Comment: `magit-unstage` does not automatically undo the last staged hunk.

Comment: No, there's no "undo" (to my knowledge); you must manually unstage it.